# linux mint black screen with cross cursor at start up

Tags: linux-mint

I have devbox with installed linux mint. Usually I use it via ssh, that's why I have no idea when this problem started: when I add second GPU or when I updated linux kernel. But yesterday I found that with connected monitor after starting I see only black screen and @cross@ as a cursor (not blinking). But it works - I still can connect to it via ssh. I tried recovery mode, all packages are updated. Have no idea how to fix this and where to look answer.
Also, I have 2 linux kernels, tried with both -- same problem. Monitor works well with the same cable and 2 another different PCs.

If it is important -- I have installed 2x 1080ti with 435.21 driver

Comment: https://forums.linuxmint.com/  may also help if you have not checked in there.

Answer (score 0):

Cross cursor (like 'X' with effects) seems to be the default cursor for 'X-windows: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System
Did you select it, or back to a 'default' mode, or ?